# How to extract content from following logs in linux server

Tags: linux, sed, extract, logfiles

I would like to retrieve the text message content and Text message detail from the following logs. How Can I do that?

```
    ./access.log.106.gz:2015-07-13 04:56:59 Sent SMS [SMSC:layered] [SVC:dtiddddddddddddddddddd6] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:1577770200] [META:] [from:+13523587779] [to:+19777470297] [flags:-1:0:-1:-1:31] [msg:8:Hello] [udh:0:]
./access.log.106.gz:2015-07-13 04:56:59 Receive DLR [SMSC:layered] [SVC:dtiLYdddddddddddddd] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:1557450200] [META:] [from:+13523500000] [to:+19777770297] [flags:-1:-1:-1:-1:8] [msg:4:ACK/] [udh:0:]
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: It is not clear with what conditions must match strings

Comment: This is also is nor clear too much for me because there is several starting point with [msg...., please consider starting point as [msg ..., so maybe we can make a query then.

Comment: Are those 2 lines your sample input? If so what's the expected output and why? Describe the algorithm. Edit your question, do not reply with that info in a comment.

Comment: i am using logstash to parse logs and also using elasticsearch and kibana to search and view graphs for the same purpose

Answer (score 1):

As per OPs latest query my suggestion would be using [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) command as follows;

```
cut -f14 -d' ' sample |tr '[]' ':'|cut -f4 -d':'
```

**Explanations:**

Here in first command we extracting only message details from log. Then modifying the output in order to extract only text message from this detail using [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) command such with next [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) command we get exact messages from log finally.

**Output:**

```
$ cut -f14 -d' ' sample |tr '[]' ':'|cut -f4 -d':' 
Hello
ACK/
```